# Why might HmsInstanceId.deleteToken and HmsInstanceId.getToken not work?

Tags: android, push-notification, huawei-mobile-services

On some devices, `HmsInstanceId.deleteToken` throws "com.huawei.hms.common.ApiException: 907135000: arguments invalid" while `HmsInstanceId.getToken` returns an empty string?

I have several huawei devices without google services on which this problem does not reproduce (eg JNY-LX1 ENUI 10.1.0). That is, on them I successfully receive a new token and receive notifications.

And there is, for example, a mediapad T5 EMUI 8.0.0 device (both with Google services and with HMS Core at the same time), on which so far it has not been possible to get either `HmsInstanceId.deleteToken` or `HmsInstanceId.getToken` to work successfully. I tried to install different versions of HMS Core on phones (I'm currently testing on 6.6.0.311). Judging by the description, my problem is very similar to https://github.com/HMS-Core/hms-push-clientdemo-android/issues/6, but the comments from there did not help me at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Check whether the system version is earlier than EMUI 10.0.

If the EMUI version of a Huawei device is **earlier than 10.0**, the token is returned through the onNewToken(String token, Bundle bundle) method. For details, kindly refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/hmsmessageservice-0000001050173839#section343314205).

---

The problem may be caused by the cache of the HMS Core (APK). Try to uninstall the HMS Core (APK) and update it may solve this issue.
If the problem persists, pls provide a detailed log for us to check.

Comment: In my case, we are talking about a device on which I cannot uninstall the HMS Core due to the protection of the operating system. But I can uninstall updates, which I have tried.

Comment: This is all that logcat outputs from the moment the application starts up until the methods HmsInstanceId.deleteToken and HmsInstanceId.getToken are called: https://pastebin.com/nDwhJmUN
Line 259 shows the error message and error number when trying to delete the token. Line 288 shows my error message after returning an empty string from the getToken method.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, can i confirm have you [enabled to the Push service](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-config-agc-0000001050170137#section9471122085218) on the AGC? If yes, can you leave your app ID, package name, and application creation time for us to check?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mx0pwPMb I posted the contents of agconnect-service.json. This is a test project. I am using `test.android.hms.debug` appId (not a package name!). I tried to build an application where the package name matches the application id (i.e. test.android.hms), but this did not affect the result. On other phones, there is no problem due to the difference between the package name and the application id.

Comment: From [the logs you provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNuRN.png), the obtained token is empty. And token has been returned using onNewToken. 
If there is no token, this error is thrown when deleted. If the token exists, the deletion is successful. 
If the token is deleted again, an error is returned. 
You can try to obtain the token, delete it, and then obtain it again to check whether the two tokens are consistent.

Comment: The token was obtained using the HmsInstanceId.getToken method (not onNewToken). On this device, you can never get a token or delete a token in any combination of calls to the HmsInstanceId.deleteToken and HmsInstanceId.getToken methods (either alone or together). And on another device (for example, JNY-LX1), the token is always obtained, regardless of the order in which the methods are called.

Comment: Can you @shirley elaborate on the mechanism by which I can get a new token and remove an old token, but using onNewToken instead of getToken? For now, HmsInstanceId.deleteToken is still throwing an exception.

Comment: 1. When the system version is earlier than EMUI 10, the getToken method is invoked to return the token through the onNewToken callback. For details, kindly refer to [this docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides/android-client-dev-0000001050042041#section11455525765).  
2. Obtain the token according to the preceding docs and then delete the token. Otherwise, you cannot check whether the token has been deleted. If there is no token or the token has been deleted again after deleted, an error will be reported.

Comment: It seems that really my problem was due to a version lower than EMUI 10.

It is a pity that this problem is so poorly described in the documentation. In my case, even with Push SDK version 6.5.0.300, the onNewToken method works correctly, and the getToken method returns an empty string.

Although, for example, the documentation says that the focus with the onNewToken method is relevant for Push SDK versions lower than 5.0.4.302.

@shirley, the whole point is already lost in our conversation, if you describe this solution in a separate new answer, then I will mark it as correct.

Comment: hi@StanleyWintergreen We are very sorry that it brings you inconvinience, but it's actually stated in [docs](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-References/hmsmessageservice-0000001050173839#section343314205). In addition, I have updated the answer to this question. If you have any further questions, please feel free to contact us.

Answer (score 0):

The developer FAQ states that this exception might be caused by a configuration issue with your agconnect-services.json. The json you posted is missing a region key/value. It might be a really basic thing, but I recommend checking that your data storage location has been configured properly. After you set the data storage location, you will need to redownload the agconnect-services.json. https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides/faq-0000001078017900

Comment: It seems that my problem was related to using the Push SDK on a device with an EMUI version lower than 10.